# Viewing IP camera via embedded VLC

Tags: vb.net, vlc, ip-camera, embedded-object

Hey all i am having some problems with viewing a stream from the IP camera via its CGI commands:

```
 http://192.168.1.99:99/videostream.cgi?user=UNhere&pwd=PWhere&resolution32=&rate=0
```

When creating the HTML page for the embedded code it looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Demo of VLC</title></head>
 <h1>Demo of VLC mozilla plugin - Example 1</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mute()
    {
    vlc.audio.toggleMute();
    }
function play()
    {
    vlc.playlist.play();
    }
function stop()
    {
    vlc.playlist.stop();
    }
function pause()
    {  
    vlc.playlist.togglePause();
    }
<body >
<!--[if IE]>
<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" id="vlc" width="720px"
    height="540px" events="True" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" >
    <param name="MRL" value="http://192.168.1.99:99/videostream.cgi?user=UNhere&pwd=PWhere&resolution32=&rate=0" />
    <param name="volume" value="50" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="loop" value="false" />
    <param name="fullscreen" value="false" />
</object>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" id="vlc" width="720px" height="540px" events="True" >
    <param name="MRL" value="http://192.168.1.99:99/videostream.cgi?user=UNhere&pwd=PWhere&resolution32=&rate=0" />
    <param name="volume" value="50" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="loop" value="false" />
    <param name="fullscreen" value="false" />
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</div>
<br />
</div>
<iframe name="action_zone" style="display:none"></iframe>
<div id="controls">
    <input type="button" onclick="play()" value="Play" />
    <input type="button" onclick="pause()" value="Pause" />
    <input type="button" onclick="stop()" value="Stop" />
    <input type="button" onclick="mute()" value="Mute" />
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now if i load up that page using IE9 it asks me to enabled blocked content and once i do i can play the stream just fine with the page above. However, loading the same page up using webbrowser1 control in vb.net results in nothing being played or asked to have permission.

So my question is: How can i reproduce the same results when loading it up in IE9 standalone in my VB.net app? I just dont get what its doing wrong in the .net VS the standalone IE9?

I've enabled every activex/script/java in the internet options that i know how too and it still produces nothing in the .net app.

Here is a screen shot with it inside IE9 standalone:
[image]

Here is the .net version of the same page:
[image]
Any help would be great!

David

Comment: `WebBrowser` uses the IE8 engine, I believe. Have you tested in IE8? (F12 Developer Tools, top menu.)

Comment: @minitech: Yep just tested it and it does work as well in IE8 in Dev section.